# DayOfWeek en CheckBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo una fecha de inicio colocada en un TextBox, y cuando ejecuto el programa me realiza un programa de fabricación con fechas iniciales y finales, quise pulir un poco el programa y agregar dos checkboxs (checkbox1 para el sábado) y un (checkbox2 para el domingo)

Cómo puedo lograr qué el programa se ejecute dependiendo el checked de los checkbox para que tome a consideración si deberá contar con la disponibilidad del sábado y/o Domingo?

```
Dim date1 As Date = CType(TextBox1.Text, Date)

Table.Rows.Add("Habilitado", "Materials", "Sending drawings for approval", DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, date1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2, date1))
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el nombre del dia apartir de la fecha de la siguiente manera y ejecutar tu formulario:

```
Private Sub getnameday()
Dim fechaCurrent As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim nameday As String = fechaCurrent.ToString("dddd")
If checkboxSabado.Checked = true and nameday = "Saturday" Then
    'Lo llamas en sabado y ejecuta tu sistema
ElseIf checboxDomingo.Checked = true and nameday = "Sunday" Then
    ''Lo llamas en domingo y ejecuta tu sistema
Else
MsgBox("No esta disponible entre semana")
End If
End Sub
```

No estoy seguro que funcione mediante copy-paste ya que originalmente lo tengo en C# y solo lo converti en linea a vb.net

Comment: No me ha funcionado, pero agradezco la respuesta y el tiempo dedicado!

Comment: Manda algun error en especifico? o no es la logica que quieres aplicar a tu sistema.

Comment: No es la lógica que deseo aplicar, lo que busco es que mi programa creado en una DataGridView muestre sólo fechas laborales de Lunes a Viernes, pero en ocasiones el usuario pueda elegir trabajar de Lunes a Sábado y/o de Lunes a Domingo apoyado de los CheckBoxs ya que usualmente se genera tiempo extra dependiendo la urgencia de cada equipo.